# select conditional data in groups

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that contains a list of machines that are loaned out to users. An entry is made each time a machine is returned our taken out. I use the following statement to return a list by user, machine#, date, and action

```
SELECT Name, Asset#, Date, InOut
FROM Table
ORDER BY Asset#, date asc
```

Which returns

```
Name      Asset#       Date        InOut
Jimmy     BER210    2009-05-08      out
Jimmy     BER210    2009-06-08      in
Jimmy     BER210    2009-07-08      out
Sam       BER220    2009-05-08      out
Sam       BER220    2009-06-08      In
Jack      BER230    2009-05-08      out
Jack      BER230    2009-06-08      In
Jack      BER230    2009-07-08      out
```

I am looking for assistance modifying that query to return ONLY the most recent entry, and ONLY if that machine is currently out.

Thanks in advance for any asstance you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `inner join` to filter out older rows per machine.  Once you have the latest rows, a `where` can be used to select machines that are "out".

```
select  Name, Asset#, Date, InOut
from    Table t
join    (
        select  Asset#
        ,       max(Date) as MaxDate
        from    Table
        group by
                Asset#
        ) filter
on      filter.Asset# = t.Asset#
        and filter.MaxDate = t.Date
where   t.InOut = 'Out'
```

Comment: upvote for a correct answer, and for correcting everyone else's

Answer (score 1):

```
select Name, Asset#, Date, InOut
 from Table
   natural join (
    select Asset#, max(Date) as Date
    from Table
    group by Asset#
  )
where InOut = 'out'
order by date desc
```

*fixed*

Comment: Shouldn't the `InOut = 'out'` be outside the subquery?

Comment: No.  the subquery is returning the assets and date of the most recent checkout.  The full query joins that with the main table to get the whole record.  However, this could behave strangely if there is more than one checkout on a particular date.  I'd need to sanity check the results against real data tho, you could be right :)

Comment: The OP says "and ONLY if that machine is currently out."  This answer in its current form would show a machine that has an "in" record after its latest "out" record.

Comment: You are correct.  My query was showing the most recent checkout for each machine. not the most recent record only if it's a checkout. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer

```
SELECT TOP 1 Name, Asset#, Date, InOut
FROM Table
WHERE InOut = 'out'
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

IN MySQL

```
SELECT Name, Asset#, Date, InOut
FROM Table
WHERE InOut = 'out'
ORDER BY Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This returns the latest time a machine went out? Don't think that's what the OP was after

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, Asset#, Date, InOut
FROM Table o
WHERE Date = (select max(Date) from 
              Table i 
              where i.Asset# = o.Asset#
             )
)
where o.in_out = 'out'
ORDER BY Asset#, date asc
```

**Edit** Changed `i.in_out` to `o.in_out` as per comment.

Comment: Should work, if you change `where i.in_out` to `where o.in_out`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Name, Asset#, Date, InOut

FROM Table WHERE InOut ='out' ORDER BY date desc